# How to Connect/Control Parallel Apex Transaction to Control Some behavior explained below

Tags: apex, trigger

I am creating Custom records by Reading incoming emails for a BookingNumber like ABC1234567 and create custom record with name ABC1234567 if custom records does not exist yet in database and if existing we relate the case with existing records,

Now, as we are using Email to Case , sometimes Customers send Emails to different Configured Email-to-Case emailaddress and apex code tries to Create custom records in independent transaction for new Booking number.

I am not able to control Duplicate Creation or if we make it unique field one Custom record creation will win rest will fail, but i need to link case record with existing Custom record in real time,

Any Suggestion?

Comment: related: https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/264267/spin-locks-with-variable-time-retry-backoffs

Comment: its Not related because i want to achieve this in Synchronous mode

Comment: Please clarify your question with a better example of the  issue