Any clean way to delay the execution of a Queuable by 20 seconds in Apex code?
The System.enqueueJob allows a minimum delay (0–10 minutes) to be specified before the Queueable will execute:
Integer delayInMinutes = 1;
ID jobId = System.enqueueJob(new MyQueueableClass(), delayInMinutes);

Anyone have a good strategy for making the minimum delay something like 20 seconds in Apex code instead of the 1 minute minimum? I'm currently leaving users waiting an unnecessary 40 seconds until my Queueable kicks in. (I've no easy way to change this logic to event based.)

Consider that the delay between calls to a Platform Event apex trigger subscriber is about (almost exactly) 1 second. You might be able to engineer an iterative delay through that, by having the trigger re-publish another event (with some incremented counter) and enqueue the Job after 20 iterations (by looking at the counter on the event) through the trigger without a delay.

Thanks @PhilW; not the prettiest but a possibility.

FOR UPDATE could work e.g. https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/264267/spin-locks-with-variable-time-retry-backoffs

Its too far fetched but why not use org wide delay which allows you set it in seconds and for every other queuable where you dont want delay or other number just use System.enqueueJob(new MyQueueableClass(), delayInMinutes); which will override org wide setting

Hi @Elijah, Never noticed that setting. We deliver an app so can't dictate/assume how such as setting will be or expect every other app to define their own delayInMinutes. For reference the setting is "From Setup, in the Quick Find box, enter Apex Settings, and then enter a value (1–600 seconds) for Default minimum enqueue delay (in seconds) for queueable jobs that do not have a delay parameter". Also suggests worth setting the delay to avoid the influence of this.

Even if you set that setting at org level, rest of the queuable classes can still run instantly ie depending on resources, only catch is all the classes will have to modified to either put 0 or any other integer. If not classes will run with the delay of 5 seconds or another far fetched idea you can introduce a schedulable class in between which will further enqueue your class but wont guarantee exactly 20 second delay

If the queueable is launched in async transaction, why not a while loop that expires after 20 elapsed seconds before enqueuing the job with delayInMinutes = 0. And if my precondition isn't true, launch a future than while loops for 20 secs before enqueueing the Queueable.

@cropredy yep likely the simplest solution.

Though not exactly the best multi-tenant option

Use a while loop that falls out after 20 elapsed seconds
When falls out, do the Queueable enqueue

If the triggering transaction is synchronous, the 20 secs may/will blow your CPU limit, so delegate to @future and do the while loop in the asynchronous future (where you have 60 secs of CPU)
There are a variety of ways to loop for 20 elapsed seconds -- pick your favorite; in one org I manage, there is this simple one:
sleep(20);

public static void sleep(Integer secs) {
    Long epochToDate = System.currentTimeMillis();
    Long epochStop = epochToDate + (secs * 1000);

    while (epochToDate <= epochStop) {
        epochToDate = System.currentTimeMillis();
    }
} 

The 20 second delay can be put into CMDT and used to adjust the delay per circumstances as experience is acquired in the operational system
